# Unexpected unmuting of all muted audio and videos when opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the code below to toggle between mute/unmute all the video and audios on the html5 page and it works fine.

If I execute the code, all of the videos and audios will be muted correctly. then if I open a new tab in the browser and then come back to the original tab the problem happens and all of the audio and videos unmute unexpectedly!

How can I fix this issue and why it happens...

Here is the code:

```
  /* mute/unmute all audios and videos */
    var allAudios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    var allVideos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    if (allAudios.length > 0 && allAudios[0].volume > 0) {
        for (var a = 0; a < allAudios.length; a++) {
            allAudios[a].volume = 0;
        }
    } else {
        for (var a = 0; a < allAudios.length; a++) {
            allAudios[a].volume = 1.0;
        }
    }


    if (allVideos.length > 0 && allVideos[0].volume > 0) {
        for (var a = 0; a < allVideos.length; a++) {
            allVideos[a].volume = 0;
        }
    } else {
        for (var a = 0; a < allVideos.length; a++) {
            allVideos[a].volume = 1.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `allAudios[0]` only checks the first element in the array, what if others have been changed?

Comment: I have one audio and one video...

Comment: Mind providing us with example audio/video element so we can replicate the issue?